# Detect on browser resize not working

Tags: jquery

Im trying to make jQuery alert on browser resize, but its not working.

http://jsfiddle.net/5m6yG/

```
function browser_resize(){
    var window_height = $(window).height();

    if ((window_height>=800)) {
        alert('800 or above!');
    }
    if ((window_height<800)) {
        alert('Under 800!');
    }
}
$(window).resize(browser_resize);
```

That is not working. When I resize my browser, even over 800, its still alerting 'Under 800!'. What is the problem?

Comment: @Dheed take the brackets off `browser_resize()` and you're correct. You want to call the function, not pass it's return value (if any) into `.resize()`

Comment: guys, it should `$(window).resize(browser_resize);`, because if we do this: `$(window).resize(browser_resize());` it calls the function everytime i refresh the page.

Comment: @Cole this `$(window).resize(browser_resize);` is wrong but not for that purpose because we want to give the resize method of jQuery the address of function to let it the resize method of jQuery run it.(like this `a=browser_resize; a();`)

Comment: @imsiso That's what I meant

Comment: ok so lets delete spa comments.(-:

Comment: Oops I'm sorry, I will delete the comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because `$(window).height();` gives you the height of the `result iframe`, not that of the browser.

See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5m6yG/6/).

```
function browser_resize(){
    $("#height").html($(window).height());
}
$(window).resize(browser_resize);
```

[Another demo with `300px height`](http://jsfiddle.net/5m6yG/7/)

```
function browser_resize(){
    var window_height = $(window).height();

    if ((window_height>=300)) {
        $("#height").html('300 or above!');
    }
    if ((window_height<300)) {
        $("#height").html('Under 300!');
    }
}
browser_resize();
$(window).resize(browser_resize);
```

Comment: yes and for testing your code you should change the result's frame size.

Answer (score 1):

For testing, I have kep the height 200 here and its working fine for me:

```
function browser_resize() {
    var window_height = $(window).height();
    console.log(window_height)
    if (window_height >= 200) {
        console.log('200 or above!');
    } else {
        console.log('Under 200!');
    }
}
$(window).resize(browser_resize);
```

You need to check the brower console for this.

Also, I think there is no need of second *if* statement here. You can put it inside the *else* part.

Comment: that still doesn't work. I tried changing it to `else` in the past..still the same problem.

Comment: As @imsiso said: _for testing your code you should change the result's frame size_ not the browser size, if you are testing on the fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Check this sout
Demo http://jsfiddle.net/5m6yG/4/

## **jQuery**

```
function browser_resize(){
    var window_height = $(window).height();

    if ((window_height>=500)) {
        alert('500 or above!');
    }
    else if ((window_height<500)) {
        alert('Under 500!');
    }
}
$(window).resize(browser_resize);
```

Comment: nothing much i just added else if statement and tested the code with smaller value n it worked you check out my demo ..!!

Comment: the problem is not in `else` and its because of frames in jsFiddle that you should change the size of result frame.